# Juliaで３次元配列をプロットしたい(4Dplot)

Tags: python3, julia

以下のような3次元配列をplotしたい場合、pythonですと

```
stage= 3×3×3 Array{Int8,3}:
    [:, :, 1] =
     1  1  1
     1  0  1
     1  1  1

    [:, :, 2] =
     1  0  1
     0  0  0
     1  0  1

    [:, :, 3] =
     1  1  1
     1  0  1
     1  1  1
```

の場合は

```
r_list = [i for i in range(0,4)]
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(r_list,r_list,r_list)
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,stage)
```

のようにmeshgridですべての座標を用意して書けますが（厳密には書いていません）、Juliaにはそういった機能はあるのでしょうか？
ネットで調べた範囲ですと、ngridが....と書いてあるところもありますが、直接的な答えは得られず質問させていただきました。

ご指導ご鞭撻のほどお願いいたします。